# Connection To The Azure Portal Timed Out With Java Custom Module

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying out writing custom java module for azure IoT Edge runtime. I am following [Tutorial: Develop a Java IoT Edge module and deploy to your simulated device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-java-module)

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04 machine and installed Azure IoT edge runtime by following [Install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on Linux (x64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux)

I have written SampleJavaModule using visual studio code tool. I am using `IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;`
 MQTT as the communication protocol. my `SamplejavaModule` gets installed on the linux machine but after 3-4 minutes it is getting exited.

when I run `sudo iotedge list` it gives me the below output

```
SampleJavaModule  failed           Failed (1) 2 minutes ago  mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/samplejavamodule:0.0.1-amd64
    edgeAgent         running          Up 40 minutes             mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0
    edgeHub           running          Up 40 minutes             mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0
    tempSensor        running          Up 15 minutes             mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.0
```

when I check the module status on the azure portal below is the status
[image]

below are the error logs

```
java.io.IOException: Could not open the connection
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceIO.open(DeviceIO.java:164)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.InternalClient.open(InternalClient.java:130)
        at com.edgemodule.App.main(App.java:126)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.exceptions.ProtocolException: Unable to establish MQTT connection
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.exceptions.PahoExceptionTranslator.convertToMqttException(PahoExceptionTranslator.java:40)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.Mqtt.connect(Mqtt.java:119)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttMessaging.start(MqttMessaging.java:56)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttIotHubConnection.open(MqttIotHubConnection.java:179)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.IotHubTransport.openConnection(IotHubTransport.java:640)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.IotHubTransport.open(IotHubTransport.java:277)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceIO.open(DeviceIO.java:160)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
```

Please suggest me how to make it work.

Thanks.

**Update: Module Code**

```
    package com.edgemodule;

import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.IotHubConnectionStatus;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;

import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceTwin.Pair;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceTwin.Property;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceTwin.TwinPropertyCallBack;

public class App {
    private static final String TEMP_THRESHOLD = "TemperatureThreshold";
    private static AtomicLong tempThreshold = new AtomicLong(25);
    private static MessageCallbackMqtt msgCallback = new MessageCallbackMqtt();
    private static EventCallback eventCallback = new EventCallback();
    private static final String INPUT_NAME = "input1";
    private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "output1";

    protected static class EventCallback implements IotHubEventCallback {
        @Override
        public void execute(IotHubStatusCode status, Object context) {
            if (context instanceof Message) {
                System.out.println("Send message with status: " + status.name());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid context passed");
            }
        }
    }

    protected static class MessageCallbackMqtt implements MessageCallback {
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public IotHubMessageResult execute(Message msg, Object context) {
            this.counter += 1;

            String msgString = new String(msg.getBytes(), Message.DEFAULT_IOTHUB_MESSAGE_CHARSET);
            System.out.println(
                   String.format("Received message %d: %s",
                            this.counter, msgString));
            if (context instanceof ModuleClient) {
                try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(msgString))) {
                    final JsonObject msgObject = jsonReader.readObject();
                    double temperature = msgObject.getJsonObject("machine").getJsonNumber("temperature").doubleValue();
                    long threshold = App.tempThreshold.get();
                    if (temperature >= threshold) {
                        ModuleClient client = (ModuleClient) context;
                        System.out.println(
                            String.format("Temperature above threshold %d. Sending message: %s",
                            threshold, msgString));
                        client.sendEventAsync(msg, eventCallback, msg, App.OUTPUT_NAME);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return IotHubMessageResult.COMPLETE;
        }
    }

    protected static class ConnectionStatusChangeCallback implements IotHubConnectionStatusChangeCallback {

        @Override
        public void execute(IotHubConnectionStatus status,
                            IotHubConnectionStatusChangeReason statusChangeReason,
                            Throwable throwable, Object callbackContext) {
            String statusStr = "Connection Status: %s";
            switch (status) {
                case CONNECTED:
                    System.out.println(String.format(statusStr, "Connected"));
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTED:
                    System.out.println(String.format(statusStr, "Disconnected"));
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.exit(1);
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTED_RETRYING:
                    System.out.println(String.format(statusStr, "Retrying"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected static class DeviceTwinStatusCallBack implements IotHubEventCallback {
        @Override
        public void execute(IotHubStatusCode status, Object context) {
            System.out.println("IoT Hub responded to device twin operation with status " + status.name());
        }
    }

    protected static class OnProperty implements TwinPropertyCallBack {
        @Override
        public void TwinPropertyCallBack(Property property, Object context) {
            if (!property.getIsReported()) {
                if (property.getKey().equals(App.TEMP_THRESHOLD)) {
                    try {
                        long threshold = Math.round((double) property.getValue());
                        App.tempThreshold.set(threshold);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Faile to set TemperatureThread with exception");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;
                System.out.println("Start to create client with MQTT protocol");
                ModuleClient client = ModuleClient.createFromEnvironment(protocol);
                System.out.println("Client created");
                client.setMessageCallback(App.INPUT_NAME, msgCallback, client);
                client.registerConnectionStatusChangeCallback(new ConnectionStatusChangeCallback(), null);
                client.open();
                client.startTwin(new DeviceTwinStatusCallBack(), null, new OnProperty(), null);
                Map<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>> onDesiredPropertyChange = new HashMap<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>>() {
                    {
                        put(new Property(App.TEMP_THRESHOLD, null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>(new OnProperty(), null));
                    }
                };
                client.subscribeToTwinDesiredProperties(onDesiredPropertyChange);
                client.getTwin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code part of your module that tries to open the connection to the EdgeHub?

Comment: Hi there, it's hard to debug without seeing the module code.  Please help us by filing an issue here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java) with all relevant logs and version information.

Comment: @YiZhong-MSFT I have updated the module code here.

Comment: @silent please check module code, That I have updated above

Comment: This question is being tracked here at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29478